# GPL Ghostscript 9.54: Unrecoverable error, exit code 255

Tags: ghostscript

android 9, in adb shell, gs command is good,  but in Android Studio ,using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gs  -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dBATCH   -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOINTERPOLATE  -sDEVICE=pxlmono  -sOutputFile=11.pcl   22.pdf");  then out error:
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: **** Could not open temporary file /tmp/gs_ptKBo1
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Could not open the scratch file /tmp/gs_ptKBo1.

- ./base/gdevp14.c:6710: gs_pdf14_device_push(): Fatal
  GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 255

why?thank you!

Comment: The error message tells you why: "Could not open temporary file /tmp/gs_ptKBo1" - not being able to open a temporary file is a fatal error. I would guess that either the "/tmp" directory doesn't exist from the POV of the binary running in Android Studio, *or* the "/tmp" directory permissions are insufficient (probably not writable). I don't know enough about Android or Android Studio to know how you'd do this, but either ensure there is a "/tmp" directory with the right permissions accessible, or use the "TEMP" environment to point gs at a different directory with the right permissions.

Comment: Oh, and not that is has anything to do with the error but setting contradicting command line params probably isn't what you want: "-dNOSAFER" and "-dPARANOIDSAFER".